# How to make NGINX respond with same protocol as in the client request?

Tags: nginx, reverse

I have an application behind NGINX LB. A client makes a series of HTTPS calls that are dependent on each other. Each response from the NGINX server to the client will be used to make the next subsequent API request. Hence, it's critical that NGINX response should have the same protocol and base URL. I tried many options but couldn't get it to work.

```
upstream testapp {
        ip_hash;
        server localhost:5555;
        server localhost:6666;
        server localhost:7777;
        keepalive 20;
     }

server {
        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        server_name  localhost;

        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;
        ssl_session_timeout 1d;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
           # root   html;
             proxy_pass http://testapp;
             proxy_set_header Host localhost:443;
             proxy_redirect http://testapp https://localhost:443;
        }
```

Everything works fine except the protocol that is returned back to the client. So for example, if client makes the following request

```
**https**://localhost:443/app
```

NGINX responds to the client as

```
http://localhost:443/app/v1/getLimits
```

instead of

```
**https**://localhost:443/app/v1/getLimits
```

Any help is truly appreciated. I am in a crunch with this issue.

Thanks
Nick

Comment: Why wouldn't you just always use HTTPS for the upstream request?

Comment: It looks like testapp responds and Nginx just passes it through. If the response is a 3xx status, you may be able to modify it using another `proxy_redirect` statement. Try `curl -I https://localhost/app`

Comment: @Brad: It will be an overkill to use HTTPS for upstream. I do not envision using NGINX on a different server other than the server where my app would be running. It would be ideal but is not required in my case.

Comment: @Nick Oh, if it's on the same box, then use HTTP for your upstream always.

Comment: @Brad, however my response back to the client is going as HTTP and not HTTPS. I want the client to be able to take this return URL and make another call through NGINX for further communication.

Comment: @Nick Nginx terminates HTTPS in this case, and HTTP can always be used upstream to your application.  Your application then doesn't have to know or care about HTTPS, and the client doesn't have to know or care that there's something behind Nginx.

Comment: Fair enough. Client in my case is the app that's making a request to NGINX using HTTPS. The client-NGINX communication is in HTTPS. As per your statement, the NGINX-upstream communication is in HTTP (for this use case). However, the upstream application is responding with another URL through NGINX that the client will use again to make another call. This URL is in "http" instead of "https" and I just figured out that the response is in the body of the response (in JSON). I want to convert this "http" to "https" before the client uses it and makes another request. Hope that helps

Comment: I resolved this issue by using ngx_http_sub module that allows me to replace strings in my response with whatever I want. Thank you all for your comments and responses.

Answer (score 1):

You may try doing this

```
proxy_pass $scheme://testapp
```

according with [nginx's documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_scheme)

```
$scheme
request scheme, “http” or “https”
```

Hope it helps you and this is my answer to your question.

But if yours backend server are inside to a local network (or vpn) and do not have contact with external world, I would try to have the communication between nginx and backend as http 1.1 because it's significantly faster than https. And I would try to maintain an opened connection between them.

And if you want to maintain comunication between nginx and backend via http but you need to know the protocol because some application logic/needs you may inject your `$scheme` as a header and you can read from your backend server.

doing

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

May help you to do it  :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it today.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. I tried both methods. The response always prepends "http" no matter what. I get a response as "http ://https ://localhost:443/testapp". I guess, I am missing something basic here. This seems to be a rudimentary LB request. I am ok communicating in "HTTP" with the upstream server since NGINX and my app will reside on the same upstream server. Any help is greatly appreciated,

Comment: My requirement is to keep the NGINX / Upstream communication in HTTP. However, when the upstream server responds back to the client through NGINX I want the communication to be HTTPS as the original request from the client.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by using ngx_http_sub module that allows me to replace strings in my response with whatever I want. Thank you all for your comments and responses.